# How do I specify in the GitHub web UI to sync my fork with a specific branch?

Tags: github

I have created a fork of a repo ("upstream"). Within the forked repo, I have created two branches, development and development1. I want to use the Sync button in the GitHub web UI to keep both branches updated. The web UI recognizes that I want to compare my development branch with upstream/development, but it then compares development1 with upstream/main. Is there a way to configure this so that development1 can also be synced to upstream/development in the web UI? I know it can be done in Git bash, but I was hoping this functionality is in the web UI too.